# Running pip install from Django Management commands

Tags: python, django, django-management-command

Let me know if this question is obvious enough and there are also duplicates of this question which I am failed for search beforehand.

I am trying to run `pip install requirements/dev.txt` from Django management command. I have a logic which is, do not try to run the script `pip ...` if the cache is unchanged. I am trying to figure out how to run this command from the DMC?

### Usage:

```
python manage.py install_prepreqs
Cache is unchanged, skipping....
```

### install_prepreqs.py

```
# I want to run `pip install requirements/dev.txt` with some additional logic.
```

Comment: (1) It's `pip install -r requirements/dev.txt` with `-r` (2) What bad about this command? It became kind of a standard if you don't want to use a `setup.py`.

Comment: Command is not a problem, running the external command is from Django management command is the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not a goot idea to run `pip` from inside Django, but if you wish then knock yourself out: [djangos custom-management-commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) and [pythons `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html)

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python) about the subprocess module.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
import subprocess

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # check your precondition logic here
        # ... your code goes here ...

        if my_condition == True:
            subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])

        # ... some more code goes here if you wish ...
```

Comment: I will verify and let you know.